# What should I use for my program to calculate the savings for more than one year?

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

```
    initial = int(input ("What is your initial balance?:"))
    interest = float(input ("What is the annual percentage for interest as a decimal?:"))
    yearsinvested = input ("How many years is the money being invested for?:")

    nextyear=initial*(1+interest)
    print ("After year 1:",nextyear ,)
```

What do I use to make it calculate+print for the amount of years inputted by the user?

Is it a while/for loop? if statement?

I've had a mental block >.<

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a while/for loop? if statement?

Yes, it's a while or for loop, based on your personal taste. Personally, I'd go for a for loop! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `for` loop. Notice that `yearsinvested` should be an `int`. You can fill in your other bits

```
yearsinvested = int(input("How many years is the money being invested for?:"))

for y in range(1, yearsinvested + 1):
    # do some stuff here
    print ("After year {}: {}".format(y, nextyear))
```